# How to read a file with mixture of data in C?

Tags: c, file-io, scanf

I am trying to read a file that is like
91242 FirstName1_LastName1 3.02

I try to use fscanf to read the file and I am confused how to read the second element that with a mixture of character and int. I'm just using one statement to read for test only. I will modify it to a while loop to read the whole text file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "linked_list.h"

int main() {
    node *list_head = NULL;
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("student.txt", "r");

    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Can not find the file.\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("File students.txt opened successfully.\n");
        printf("Linked list built from file students.txt successfully\n");
    }

    student s;
    fscanf(file,"%d%s%lf", &s.id,s.name,&s.gpa);
    insert_last(&list_head, s);
    print_list(list_head);
}
```

Here is what i got when I print it out.

91242   FirstName1_LastName1)\�@�4� 3.02

Here is my student.c document

```
#include "student.h"

 

void print_student(student student_record){

  printf("%d\t%s\t%.2f\n", student_record.id, student_record.name,

  student_record.gpa);

}
```

And here is the definition of student.

  `typedef struct{ int id; char name[20]; double gpa; } student;`

Comment: It's not a mixture of character and int. The string "Foo42" has 5 characters: 1 uppercase letter, 2 lowercase letters and 2 digits. The specifier `"%s"` does not care, as long as they're not whitespace (space, tab, enter, ...)

Comment: Are you saying that the shown code does not work? Because it looks like it would. What happens if you run it? Maybe forget about the additional risks of a linked list, i.e. delete that line, just for testing and making a [mre]. Just print what you read, one line, no list, no loop. What is the output?

Comment: Also try putting spaces into your format string: `%d %s $lf`

Comment: @lxop that is not necessary with those format specifiers.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Please note you should post a [mcve]. Take your time to make the it really minimal. Remove all the list stuff, just immediately pring what you've just read.

Comment: Indeed it isn't. I've just tried running this code with the linked_list and student bits ripped out, and it works fine. So also don't know what the problem actually is.

Comment: Please check the return value from `fscanf` which should be `3`. And, when `file == NULL` you should not continue the code.

Comment: Sorry not being clear. I have posted my output and student.c document